# JS function triggering twice for only one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, onclick, click

Scenario:

Function one:

```
$(document).on('click','.select_lens_prescp_option',function(){  ....       });
```

Function two:

```
  $(document).on('click','.lens_manual_change',function(event){
    // event.preventDefault();
    $('#lens_edit_manual_change_'+
    $(this).data('suborder')+",#contacts_prescription_manual_change_"+
    $(this).data('suborder')+
    ",#lens_save_manual_change_"+$(this).data('suborder')).toggle('slow');
  });
```

Now I want to do the same functionality inside click event of class `lens_manual_change` but though click event of class `select_lens_prescp_option`

```
$(document).on('click','.select_lens_prescp_option',function(){
  ....
  if(form.find('.lens_form_fields').is(':hidden')){
      form.find('.lens_manual_change').trigger('click');   // this is the step I performed
    }
});
```

Issue: the first function gets triggered twice.

Comment: Which "first function", "function one" or "function two"? Your best bet is to provide a [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button). Even if you don't, at a minimum, we need to see the HTML this is acting on.

Answer (score 0):

`event.stopPropagation()` function inside inner event handler will work.

```js
$('.first').on('click', function(){
 alert(1);
});
$('.second').on('click', function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
 alert(2);
});
```

```css
.first{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:white;
}
.second{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top:50px;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='first'>
  <div class='second'>
  </div>
</div>
```

[documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)